# Angular - Scroll Event only page scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to check scroll event for a "show more" features.

Im using:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
```

and this code:

```
scroll = (event: any): void => {
        const number = event.srcElement.scrollTop;

        this.show_scroll_top = false;
        if (event.target.scrollTop >= 500) {
            this.show_scroll_top = true;
        }

        if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight) {
              this.showMorFunctionFoo();
        }

    };
```

Unfortunally the scroll listen to every scroll in page, for example a scroll inside a DropDown etc...

How can I listen ONLY the PAGE scroll ignoring everyelse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to use hostListener from Angular (https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) in your page component

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) 
onScroll($event:Event):void {
   ... your logic here
};
```

or you could use something like that

```
scroll = (event: any): void => {
    if (event.target.getAttribute('id') === YOU_PAGE_HTML_ID) {
       ... your logic here
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with this workaround:  if (event.target.tagName === "MAT-SIDENAV-CONTENT") ...